# I have big database on mongodb and can't find and use my info

Tags: mongodb, nosql

### This my code:

```
    db.test.find() {
    "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9"),
   "title" : "Sir",
   "name" : {
   "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7ff"),
   "first_name" : "Farid"
    },
   "addresses" : [
    {
   "city" : "Baku",
   "country" : "Azerbaijan"
   },{
   "city" : "Susha",
   "country" : "Azerbaijan"
   },{
   "city" : "Istanbul",
   "country" : "Turkey"
   }
   ]
   }
```

> I want get output only all city. Or I want get output only all country. How can i do it?

Comment: Can you explain more what exactly you want to find out

Comment: i wand find out for example only all city

Comment: When someone asks you to "explain" it means to add "more detail" to your question. Give more data. Show expected results. I'm sensing that english is not you main language here so examples are the key to making your point clear. Edit your question. The link is there for a reason.

Comment: I want get output only all city. Or I get output only all country. How can i do it? I want query structure, or when my data model wrong change data structure. Yes English is not my mother language

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% about your code example, because if your 'find' by ID there's no need to search by anything else... but I wonder whether the following can help:

```
db.test.insert({name:'farid', addresses:[
    {"city":"Baku", "country":"Azerbaijan"},
    {"city":"Susha", "country":"Azerbaijan"},
    {"city" : "Istanbul","country" : "Turkey"}
]});
db.test.insert({name:'elena', addresses:[
    {"city" : "Ankara","country" : "Turkey"},
    {"city":"Baku", "country":"Azerbaijan"}
]});
```

Then the following will show all countries:

```
db.test.aggregate(
 {$unwind: "$addresses"},
 {$group: {_id:"$country", countries:{$addToSet:"$addresses.country"}}}
);
```

result will be

```
{ "result" : [ 
        { "_id" : null,
           "countries" : [ "Turkey", "Azerbaijan"]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Maybe there are other ways, but that's one I know.
With 'cities' you might want to take more care (because I know cities with the same name in different countries...).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, there may be two underlying issues here:

First, it looks like you are trying to query a Collection called "test". Often times, "test" is the name of an actual database you are using. My concern, then, is that you are trying to query the database "test" to find any collections that have the key "city" or "country" on any of the internal documents. **If this is the case, what you actually need to do is identify all of the collections in your database, and search them individually to see if any of these collections contain documents that include the keys you are looking for.**

(For more information on how the db.collection.find() method works, check the MongoDB documentation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)

Second, if this is actually what you are trying to do, all you need to for each collection is define a query that only returns the key of the document you are looking for. If you get more than 0 results from the query, you know documents have the "city" key. If they don't return results, you can ignore these collections. *One caveat here is if data about "city" is in embedded documents within a collection. If this is the case, you may actually need to have some idea of which embedded documents may contain the key you are looking for.*